# How to return errors from a node application so they are captured by $post.fail()

Tags: node.js, express, bluebird

I have a simple chat application. In index.html I have a form with an input with id "nick". When I submit this form I want to create a user if this user doesn't already exist in the chatroom. If the user does exist (or if there is another error) I want to be able to display a helpful error message.

Here I've listed the 3 pieces of code that do this.

I want to handle any errors in the user creation in index.html using $post.fail(). How can I do this? As it stands, if a user already exists Express throws the following exception on the line "throw new Error('user already exists');":

"Unhandled rejection Error: user already exists at c:\Users\Matt\Documents\code\chat\app\routes\room.js:24:19"

Does this mean I am supposed to call Promise.reject() somewhere? Is there a standard way of returning errors so they are captured by $post.fail()?

index.html

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $.post(window.location.href + 'users/create', { nickname: $('#nick').val() })
    .done(function(res) {
        // user created successfully
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // user create failed
        // show error message
    });
    return false;
});
```

room.js - Room Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

var roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, index: { unique: true } },
    users: [{ type: String, required: true, trim: true }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Room', roomSchema);
```

room.js - Room Route

```
var express = require('express');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('../../config');
var Room = require('../models/room');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/create', function(req, res) {
    var promise = Room.findOne({ name: req.roomname }).exec();

    promise.then(function(room) {
        if (!room) {
            var newRoom = Room({
                name: req.roomname,
                users: []
            });
            return newRoom.save();
        }
        return room;
    })
    .then(function(room) {
        if (room.users.indexOf(req.body.nickname) > -1) {
            throw new Error('user already exists');
        } 
        room.users.push(req.body.nickname);
        return room.save();
    })
    .then(function(room) {
        var token = jwt.sign(req.body.nickname, config.secret); 
        return res.json({ nickname: req.body.nickname, token: token });   
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        throw err; // I want any errors to bubble back up to the fail() in index.html so I can display a message
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the request to be considered failed due to internal processing error, you should return 5xx as the response status.

```js
    .catch(function(err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
```

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

> 10.5 Server Error 5xx
>
> Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases
>   in    which the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of
>   performing the request. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the 
>   server SHOULD include an entity containing an explanation of the
>   error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
>   condition. User agents SHOULD display any included entity to the
>   user. These response codes are applicable to any request method.